# Storing powerpoint files (.ppt and .pptx) in SQLite database in Android

Tags: sqlite

Can you directly store .ppt and .pptx files in the SQLite database in android?
if so, How? sorry im still new to android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be perfectly fine to store the file as a BLOB in an SQLite database. Basically you would need to get a byte array of the file's contents, and then store it in the database.

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/path/to/file.ppt");
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int read;
while ((read = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
  baos.write(buffer, 0, read);
}
baos.flush();
byte[] fileByteArray = baos.toByteArray();
```

You can now store `fileByteArray` in the database.

Comment: so you mean we need to convert the ppt files to an image first before we can store it to the database as BLOB?